# Datediff SQL date conversion

Tags: sql, date, type-conversion, date-conversion

I am trying to use datediff on a  date/time column. The date/time column is in  `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format and from what I have read online Datediff works with `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` format.

I have tried to convert bit I am facing problems

```
DATEDIFF(minute, convert(varchar(c.duration, 20)), '1970/01/01 00:00:00') as "Resolution Target"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Datediff is a product specific function, and convert too.)

Comment: it's a Service Now database where I'm connecting over ODBC. From what I read it's a MySQL DB. Even our SN Admins don't know

Comment: Do `select version();` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on database you are using ,if you are using Oracle 'yyyy-mm-dd',if it is SQL Server 'yyyy/mm/dd' can be used as datediff function.

DATEDIFF(minute, convert(varchar(c.duration), 20) , '1970/01/01 00:00:00') as "Resolution Target"